# Number contained in an odd number of sets

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a homework problem which i can solve only in `O(max(F)*N)` ( `N` is about `10^5` and `F` is `10^9`) complexity, and i hope you could help me. I am given `N` sets of 4 `integer` numbers (named `S, F, a` and `b`); Each set of 4 numbers describe a set of numbers in this way: The first a successive numbers, starting from `S` included are in the set. The next `b` successive numbers are not, and then the next `a` numbers are, repeating this until you reach the superior limit, `F`. For example for `S=5;F=50;a=1;b=19` the set contains `(5,25,45); S=1;F=10;a=2;b=1` the set contains `(1,2,4,5,7,8,10);`

I need to find the integer which is contained in an odd number of sets. It is guaranteed that for the given test there is ONLY 1 number which respects this condition.

I tried to go trough every number between `min(S)` and `max(F)` and check in how many number of sets this number is included, and if it is included in an odd number of sets, then this is the answer. As i said, in this way I get an `O (F*N)` which is too much, and I have no other idea how could I see if a number is in a odd number of sets.

If you could help me I would be really grateful. Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad English and explanation!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501936/sets-of-numbers?

Comment: Looks like the membership test is `[S, F, a, b](n) { return (n < F) && ((n - S) % (a + b) < a); }`  Does that help?  (You may be apply to apply some properties of modulo arithmetic.)

Answer (score 3):

### Hint

I would be tempted to use bisection.

Choose a value x, then count how many numbers<=x are present in all the sets.

If this is odd then the answer is <=x, otherwise >x.

This should take time O(Nlog(F))

### Alternative explanation

Suppose we have sets

```
[S=1,F=8,a=2,b=1]->(1,2,4,5,7,8) 
[S=1,F=7,a=1,b=0]->(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) 
[S=6,F=8,a=1,b=1]->(6,8)
```

Then we can table:

N(y) = number of times y is included in a set,

C(z) = sum(N(y) for y in range(1,z)) % 2

```
y  N(y)  C(z)
1  2     0
2  2     0
3  1     1
4  2     1
5  2     1
6  2     1
7  2     1
8  2     1
```

And then we use bisection to find the first place where C(z) becomes 1.

Comment: Could you explain with a bit more depth why this would work? It's not clear that divide-and-conquer works on this problem in the way you suggest.

Comment: Thank you, I see it now. (The unmentioned trick, of course, is how to count very quickly. That just comes down to some careful math.)

Comment: Doesn't `N` take `O(F)` memory? That's quite a lot in the worst case. And are you saying you can find `N` in under `O(F)` for all `y`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it'd be useful to find a way to perform set operations, particularly intersection, on these sets without having to generate the actual sets. If you could do that, the intersection of all these sets in the test should leave you with just one number. Leaving the `a` and `b` part aside, it's easy to see how you'd take the intersection of two sets that include all integers between S and F: the intersection is just the set with S=max(S1, S2) and F=min(F1, F2).

That gives you a starting point; now you have to figure out how to create the intersection of two sets consider `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

XOR to the rescue.

Take the numbers from each successive set and XOR them with the contents of the result set. I.e., if the number is currently marked as "present", change that to "not present", and vice versa.

At the end, you'll have one number marked as present in the result set, which will be the one that occurred an odd number of times. All of the others will have been XORed an even number of times, so they'll be back to the original state.

As for complexity, you're dealing with each input item exactly once, so it's basically linear on the total number of input items -- at least assuming your operations on the result set are constant complexity. At least if I understand how they're phrasing things, that seems to meet the requirement.

Comment: Wouldn't this require generating all the items in all the sets? That's `O(N*F)`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like S is assumed to be non-negative. Given your desire for an `O(max(F)*N)` time boundary you can use a sieving-like approach.

Have an array of integers with an entry for each candidate number (that is, every number between min(S) and max(F)). Go through all the quadruples and add 1 to all array locations associated with included numbers represented by each quadruple. At the end, look through the array to see which count is odd. The number it represents is the number that satisfies your conditions.

This works because you're going under N quadruples, and each one takes O(max(F)) or less time (assuming S is always non-negative) to count the included numbers. That gives you O(max(F)*N).

Comment: Still way too much under the given upper limits.